# How can I plot a list returned by the mathematica solution to in bounded integer equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integer, plot, diophantine

So I have a set of bounded diophantine equations that specify lines on the plane. I want to make mathematica plot the intersection of two of these equations so I can see what they look like.

So far I have something like:

> Solve[0 < x - y < 3 && -1 < 2 x - y < 2, {x, y}, Integers]

which returns some structure like:

> {{x -> -2, y -> -4}, {x -> -1, y -> -3}, {x -> -1, y -> -2}, {x -> 0, 
>     y -> -1}}

but how can I now make mathematica plot this so I can see the resulting shape. Preferably I would like the plot to consider every 'point' to be a 1x1 square.

Also, I wonder if there is a better way to do such things. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the data you wish to plot by transforming the list `Solve[]` returns. This can  done as

```
 data = {x, y} /. Solve[0 < x - y < 3 && -1 < 2 x - y < 2, {x, y}, Integers]
```

More generally, you can make `Solve` return the solution in a list format (rather than as a set of rules) using the following trick:

```
 data = Solve[0 < x - y < 3 && -1 < 2 x - y < 2, {x, y}, Integers] /. Rule[a_,b_]->b
```

For plotting, among many alternatives, you can use `ListPlot` as

```
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledSquare]", FontSize -> 16]}]
```

to get the following output

[image: output image]

You can further refine it using many styling and other options of `ListPlot`. For example, you can join the points

```
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledSquare]", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

to get

[image: joined plot]

EDIT: To play with the marker placement and size there are several alternatives. Using `ListPlot` you can get what you need in either of the two ways:

```
 (* Alternative 1: use fontsize to change the marker size *)
 lp1 := ListPlot[{#} & /@ #1, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledSquare]", FontSize -> Scaled[#2]]},
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, 
  Line@#1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] &;
 (* usage example *)
 lp1 @@ {data, .30}

 (* Alternative 2: use the second parameter of PlotMarkers to control scaled size *)
 lp2 := ListPlot[{#} & /@ #1, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@{Rectangle[]}, #2}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, 
 Line@#1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] &
 (* usage example *)
 lp2 @@ {data, 1/5.75}
```

In both cases, you need to use `Epilog`, otherwise the lines joining points are occluded by the markers. Both alternatives produce the following output:

[image: listplot with markers]

Alternatively, you can use `Graphics`, `RegionPlot`, `ContourPlot`, `BubbleChart` with appropriate transformations of `data` to get results similar to the one in `ListPlot` output above.

**Using Graphics primitives:**

```
 (* data transformation to define the regions *)
 trdataG[data_, size_] :=  data /. {a_, b_} :> 
         {{a - size/2, b - size/2}, {a + size/2, b + size/2}};
 (* plotting function *)
 gr := Graphics[
      {
      {Hue[RandomReal[]], Rectangle[##]} & @@@ trdataG @@ {#1, #2}, 
      GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Thick, Point@#1, Line@#1}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}
      }, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
      Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] &
 (* usage example *)
 gr @@ {data, .99}
```

**Using BubbleChart:**

```
 (* Transformation of data to a form that BubbleChart expects *)
 dataBC[data_] := data /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, 1};
 (* custom markers *)
 myMarker[size_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :=
      {EdgeForm[], Rectangle[{(1/2) (xmin + xmax) - size/2, (1/2) (ymin + ymax) - 
       size/2}, {(1/2) (xmin + xmax) + size/2, (1/2) (ymin + ymax) + size/2}]};
 (* charting function *)
 bc := BubbleChart[dataBC[#1], ChartElementFunction -> myMarker[#2], 
       ChartStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], Axes -> True, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}}, 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameTicks -> All, 
       Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, Line@#1}] &
 (* usage example *)
 bc @@ {data, .99}
```

**Using RegionPlot:**

```
 (* Transformation of data to a form that RegionPlot expects *)
  trdataRP[data_, size_] :=  data /. {a_, b_} :> 
            a - size/2 <= x <= a + size/2 && b - size/2 <= y <= b + size/2
 (* charting function *)
 rp := RegionPlot[Evaluate@trdataRP[#1, #2], {x, -5, 1}, {y, -5, 1}, 
          AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
          PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}}, 
          PlotStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], FrameTicks -> All, 
          PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
          Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, Line@#1}] &
 (* usage example *)
 rp @@ {data, .99}
```

**Using ContourPlot:**

```
 (* Transformation of data to a form that ContourPlot expects *)
 trdataRP[data_, size_] :=   data /. {a_, b_} :> 
            a - size/2 <= x <= a + size/2 && b - size/2 <= y <= b + size/2;
 trdataCP[data_, size_] := Which @@ Flatten@
           Thread[{trdataRP[data, size], Range@Length@data}];
 (* charting function *)
 cp := ContourPlot[trdataCP[#1, #2], {x, -5, 1}, {y, -5, 1}, 
             AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
             PlotRange -> {{-5, 1}, {-5, 1}}, FrameTicks -> All, 
             ExclusionsStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
             ColorFunction -> Hue, 
             Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, Line@#1}] &
 (* usage example *)
 cp @@ {data, .99}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I wonder if it is possible to make the markers fill the integer that they represent so that, e.g the integer coordinate (1,1) consumes everything such that the top right corner of the unit square is this coordinate?

Comment: @user1170304 I am not sure I interpreted the requirement in your comment correctly. Pls check the edit and let me know if it meets what you intended.

Comment: Hmmm I guess this is a little difficult to explain but I want the markers to cover the are up to their unit square boundaries. So if (0,0) is the point then the marker should cover the square formed by the coordinates (1/2,1/2), (1/2,-1/2), (-1/2,-1/2), (-1/2,1/2) or something similar. Is this possible? Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

may be

```
sol = Solve[0 < x - y < 3 && -1 < 2 x - y < 2, {x, y}, Integers];
pts = Cases[sol, {_ -> n_, _ -> m_} :> {n, m}];
ListPlot[pts, Mesh -> All, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]

Can also extract the points to plot using

```
{#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ sol
```